# Soundcloud iFrame Embed Leaking Memory

Tags: iframe, memory-leaks, embed, soundcloud

I'm currently building a single-page backbone app that embeds up to 10 separate Soundcloud iFrames on a single page. Users can then view other pages, each of which contain their own set of iFrames.

I've noticed that each time a new set of iframes is loaded the memory consumption for the tab increases roughly 80-100MB (according to the Chrome Task Manager). This memory is never relinquished, so after a few clicks the tab easily reaches 300MB and becomes intolerably slow.   This slowness occurs in both Chrome 20 and Firefox 13.

After each page change I've tried .remove()'ing all the iframes as well as clearing out the container element via .html('') and neither stems the memory growth.

Provided in this gist is sample code that exhibits the same behavior as described above. On each load the individual iFrame consumes roughly 10MB of additional memory.
https://gist.github.com/3202151

Is the Soundcloud embed code doing something to maintain a handle to the iframe and preventing it from being GC'd? Is there another way I can remove the elements from the DOM to avoid the memory bloat?

Note: I cannot add all the tracks to a single set which can be loaded once since tracks being embedded are not my own.

Comment: I'm interested in this matter since I use <IFRAME> to embbed Soundcloud player (s) on pages from my website too.

Answer (score 2):

I have been running into a similar problem.  I'm using the SoundCloud js sdk to stream audio in a custom player on my site.  I got it running and let it go all night (because I was suspicious of the swf size).  Sure enough, in the morning the swf was massive and my computer was noticeably slow.  The SoundCloud sdk uses SoundManager2 to stream/play audio, so it creates a soundManager object which you can access in JS.  I ended up managing the swf size by calling

```
soundManager.reboot();
```

...between each song that plays.  In your case you could call it between the various pages, keeping the memory to the 80-100MB max at a time.  It increases the load time by a fraction of a second, but that's a small price to pay for fixing the ever-growing memory issue.

I'm not sure if the iframe player also creates the soundManager object, but if so, give this a try!

Check out the SoundManager2 documentation here:

http://www.schillmania.com/projects/soundmanager2/doc/#soundmanager-reboot